# ¿Cómo llenar una matriz con valores de vectores?

Tags: java

la salida es así:
entra el mensaje "abcdefgh" y y esto lo convierto en un arreglo ahora esto se veria asi: vMensaje = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h] y  luego dentro del for lo convierto a binario cada carácter ahora la salida es así

CONVIRTIENDO LOS CARACTERES A BINARIO
[0] = [a] = 1100001
[1] = [b] = 1100010
[2] = [c] = 1100011
[3] = [d] = 1100100
[4] = [e] = 1100101
[5] = [f] = 1100110
[6] = [g] = 1100111
[7] = [h] = 1101000

```
String mensaje = "abcdefgh" , b;
    int a = 0;
    char []vMensaje = mensaje.toCharArray();

    System.out.print("CONVIRTIENDO LOS CARACTERES A BINARIO");
    for (int i = 0; i < vMensaje.length; i++) 
    {
        a = vMensaje[i];
        b = Integer.toBinaryString(a);
        System.out.print("["+ i +"] = " + "["+ vMensaje[i] +"] = " + b);
    }
```

**la variable vMensaje = [1100001,1100010, 1100011,1100100,1100101,1100110,1100111,1101000] esta así ahora**,
entonces lo que esta convertido en binario se a guardado en el vector vMensaje y lo que esta en binario necesito ponerlo en una matriz: la salid a que quiero que de es:

1 1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 0 0 0

la primera fila es el carácter "a"la siguiente es "b" y así sucesivamente hasta "h"

Comment: Bro si explicaras la salida o aun mas tu duda seria mas fácil que te pueda(n) ayudar, hay tipos de matrices, te aconsejo que especifiques cual de todas.

Comment: ya trate de explicar mejor en la descripción tal vez me entiendes

Comment: Y cual es el problema especifico que tenes? recorres ese vector, y por cada posicion lo pasas a una posicion de la matriz... cual seria el problema especifico?

Comment: ese exactamente no se como recorrer el vector

Answer (score 0):

Bro aun con tu breve explicación no entendí muy bien, pero hice algo y espero te ayude para orientarte o sea lo que estas buscando:

```
String mensaje = "abcdefgh";//Tu cadena de String
char []vMensaje = mensaje.toCharArray();
//Creamos un vector o arreglo del mismo tamaño que el total de las letras del String
String[] binarios_vector = new String[vMensaje.length];
System.out.println("CONVIRTIENDO LOS CARACTERES A BINARIO");
System.out.println("Binarios Guardados en el vecto");
for (int i = 0; i < vMensaje.length; i++) {
   //Es practicamente lo que tenias pero en una linea
   binarios_vector[i] = Integer.toBinaryString(vMensaje[i]);
   //System.out.print("["+ i +"] = " + "["+ vMensaje[i] +"] = " + b);
   //Imprimes la posición y el valor que esta ocupa en el arreglo
   System.out.println("Pos: "+ i + " val: " + binarios_vector[i]);
}
```

Espero te sirva o te ayude un poco. Saludos